# VB.NET .txt file manipulation

Tags: vb.net

currently working on a school project, we have tocode (in vb.net) a program that reads a txt file with x and y coordinates of different points and do distance calculations between every two points and write over the file the distance.

the txt file looks something like this :

```
596;226  
506;179  
412;298  
583;291   
...etc
```

so my goal is to calculate dx and dy (difference between each 2 lines coordinates) so i get the distance afterwards.

only problem is i'm stuck at how can get dx and dy (7days now)
for exemple dx for line 1 and 2 is (506-596), for line 2 is (412-506) and so on for all the points with dy too.

here is what i've been attempting in vain (majority of the code was just copy/paste from the net).

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1


Private Sub FichierTexteToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FichierTexteToolStripMenuItem.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "fichier texte| *.txt"
    Dim nbLigne As Integer
    nbLigne = 0
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sr As StreamReader
        sr = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim x, y As String
        Dim dx, dy As String
        Dim txtTotal As Object
        Dim ligne = sr.ReadLine()
        Dim tabl() As Object
        tabl = Split(ligne, ";") 'la taille de tableau represente le nombre de bloc qui ksont séparer par les separateur
        txtTotal = ligne + vbCrLf


        'While Not ligne Is Nothing
        '    ligne = sr.ReadLine
        '    txtTotal = txtTotal + ligne + vbCrLf

        '    tabl = Split(ligne, ";") 'la taille de tableau represente le nombre de bloc qui ksont séparer par les separateur
        '    nbLigne = nbLigne + 1
        'End While
        x = tabl(0)
        y = tabl(1)

        While Not ligne Is Nothing
            ligne = sr.ReadLine

            tabl = Split(ligne, ";")
            dx = tabl(0) - x
            dy = tabl(1) - y

        End While


        'test
        Label2.Text = dx
        Label3.Text = dy

        'Label1.Text = Calculs.distance(dx, dy)

    Else : Close()

    End If

End Sub



End Class
```

thank you, hope someone will get me out of this problem :)

Comment: Ever heard of the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)? French: [Théorème de Pythagore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Pythagore). You will need it in order to calculate the distance between 2 points in the 2-D space!

Comment: It's not a problem on how to calculate i've the forumula done in a module, but i need dx and dy for it.  dist = Math.Sqrt((dx) ^ 2 + (dy) ^ 2)

Comment: You have ``dx`` and ``dy`` as strings. To do any kind of maths with them you need to change them to integers (or singles or doubles)

Comment: the codewon't work even when i change them to double.

Comment: When you say "won't work"... do you get the wrong answer? Or does it not run?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare

```
Dim tabl() As String
```

Since the function `Split` returns a String array. You cannot do math calculations with strings. So you must convert all the strings to numbers. E.g. to `Double`.

The `dx` and `dy` need to be numbers

```
Dim dx = Double.Parse(tabl(0)) - Double.Parse(x)
Dim dy = Doubel.Parse(tabl(1)) - Double.Parse(y)
```

---

You could make your code clearer by extracting the reading and conversion part into a separate function. In this example I also added some validity checks

```
Private Function TryReadCoords(sr As StreamReader, ByRef x As Double, ByRef y As Double) _
    As Boolean

    Dim ligne = sr.ReadLine()
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ligne) Then
        Return False
    End If

    Dim parts = Split(ligne, ";")
    Return _
        parts.Length = 2 AndAlso _
        Double.TryParse(parts(0), x) AndAlso _
        Double.TryParse(parts(1), y)
End Function
```

You can enlcose the `StreamReader` into a `Using` statement. It automatically closes the file at the end.

Using this new function, the code now looks much simpler:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim x0, y0, x1, y1 As Double

    If TryReadCoords(sr, x0, y0) Then
        While TryReadCoords(sr, x1, y1)
            Dim dx = x1 - x0
            Dim dy = y1 - y0

            'Do calculations here ...

            x0 = x1
            y0 = y1
        End While
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i did that, now i'm getting this error in the dim dx line :Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: I don't see what there is in your string, but I guess there is an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: The txt file is ok i guess no line at the end, could it be another error in the code ?  and what should i delete in the previous function then (sorry i'm still very new to coding)

Comment: Tank you so much, yeah the last code seems simpler, only thing is i don't know what to delete from the previous code and how to manage everything, could you please right all the code instead of part of it ? i feel so lost with all the parts especially since i don't understand what they do so well.thank you gain for your precious help

Comment: The only other code parts in `FichierTexteToolStripMenuItem_Click` in my test code are the `OpenFileDialog` related things. `OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "fichier texte| *.txt"` and `If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then`. I removed all other `Dim`s. The VB compiler tells you what is wrong. It helps to read the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net provides a `Point`<sup>*</sup> structure. Use that; as you read each line, parse it into a `Point` instance.

When you can do that much, write a method that accepts two `Point`s and returns the distance between them. This helps you because it pulls out all of the things that distract from the objective or confuses you:

```
 Public Function Distance(ByVal p1 As Point, ByVal p2 As Point) As Double
     Return Point.Subtract(p1, p2).Length
 End Function
```

This looks like homework, so your professor is probably expecting you to do the whole
`√((x₁ - x)² + (y₁ - y₂)²)` formula, but if you need that writing it *on your own* is the point of the assignment.

---

<sub>* Note the code example uses `System.Windows.Point` rather than `System.Drawing.Point`, which requires adding a reference to the project</sub>